# PHP replacing 'editable' areas in html files

Tags: php, arrays, forms, template-engine

I'm working on a tool to replace tagged areas in a html document. I've had a look at a few php template systems, but they are not really what I am looking for, so here is what I am after as the "engine" of the system. The template itself has no php and I'm searching the file for the keyword 'editable' to set the areas that are updatable. I don't want to use a database to store anything, instead read everything from the html file itself.

It still has a few areas to fix, but most importantly, I need the part where it iterates over the array of 'editable' regions and updates the template file.

Here is test.html (template file for testing purposes):

```
<html>

<font class="editable">
This is editable section 1
</font>
<br><br><hr><br>
<font class="editable">
This is editable section 2
</font>

</html>
```

I'd like to be able the update the 'editable' sections via a set of form textareas. This still needs a bit of work, but here is as far as I've got:

```
<?php

function g($string,$start,$end){ 
     preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '(.*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $string, $m); 
     $out = array(); 

     foreach($m[1] as $key => $value){ 
       $type = explode('::',$value); 
       if(sizeof($type)>1){ 
          if(!is_array($out[$type[0]])) 
             $out[$type[0]] = array(); 
          $out[$type[0]][] = $type[1]; 
       } else { 
          $out[] = $value; 
       } 
     } 
  return $out; 
}; 

// GET FILES IN DIR
   $directory="Templates/";
   // create a handler to the directory
    $dirhandler = opendir($directory);
    // read all the files from directory
    $i=0;
    while ($file = readdir($dirhandler)) {
        // if $file isn't this directory or its parent 
        //add to the $files array
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
                $files[$i]=$file; 
          //echo $files[$i]."<br>";
          $i++;                
        }   
    };
//echo $files[0];

?>

<div style="float:left; width:300px; height:100%; background-color:#252525; color:#cccccc;">
<form method="post" id="Form">
Choose a template:
<select>
<?php
// Dropdown of files in directory
foreach ($files as $file) {
  echo "<option>".$file."</option>"; // do somemething to make this $file on selection. Refresh page and populate fields below with the editable areas of the $file html
};
?>
</select>
<br> 
<hr>
Update these editable areas:<br>

<?php


$file = 'test.html';  // make this fed from form dropdown (list of files in $folder directory)
$html = file_get_contents($file);

$start = 'class="editable">';
$end = '<';

$oldText = g($html,$start,$end);

$i = 0;
foreach($oldText as $value){
  echo '<textarea value="" style="width: 60px; height:20px;">'.$oldText[$i].'</textarea>';  // create a <textarea> that will update the editable area with changes
  // something here
  $i++;
};

// On submit, update all $oldText values in test.html with new values.
?>
<br><hr>
&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>  
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:300px;">
<?php include $file; // preview the file from dropdown. The editable areas should update when <textareas> are updated ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I know this answer is a little more involved, but I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i correctly understand what you want to achieve. But it seems I would do that in jquery.

You can get all html elements that has the "editable" class like this :

```
$(".editable")
```

You can iterate on them with :

```
$(".editable").each(function(index){
    alert($(this).text()); // or .html()
    // etc... do your stuff
});
```

If you have all your data in a php array. You just need to pass it to the client using json. Use php print inside a javascript tag.

```
<?php

print "var phparray = " . json_encode($myphparray);

?>
```

I think it would be better to put the work on the client side (javascript). It will lower the server work load (PHP).

But as I said, I don't think I've grasped everything you wanted to achive.